# Java check if Map values are the same

Tags: java

I have a Map, and I want to return True, if the values are the same like here:

```
{a=2, b=2, c=2}
```

and return false, if they aren't, like here:

```
{a=2, b=2, c=2 d=1}
```

How can I check this with java?

Comment: Do you mean `map1.equals(map2)`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think he means that values should be the same within the same map.

Comment: `Sets.newHashSet(theMap.values()).size() == 1` with guava `Sets`

Comment: Yes, within the map

Comment: To check all the names are the same you can use `new HashSet<>(map.values()).size == 1`

Comment: @RC One of the problems with using a third party library is it can be more complicated than just using the build in libraries.

Comment: @marstran Wasn't sure about hashset ctor and too lazy to fetch the javadoc :p

Comment: @RC Fair point.

Comment: I really don't like the answers that have `.size() == 1` somewhere in them.  These will keep comparing values and counting them, even after they find two values that are different.  If it's a big map, this is a complete waste of processing time.